# git log on Debian isn't showing local / remote matching branches names near the commit ids. On Windows, git-bash was displaying them

Tags: git, debian, git-bash

I used `git-bash` on `Windows 7`, and I found very convenient when doing a

`git log`

that local or remote branch(es) name(s) were mentionned near the *sha-1* of each commit where it was accurate.

It was really useful at the time I had to do a `rebase -i`, to select the good commit id to summarize my local branch before pushing it.

Going to `Debian 9` now, I do not need to install `git-bash`. However, a `git log` no more mention me the accorded branches of my commit ids. Is this a special customisation of my `git log` command that `git-bash` does and that I can reproduce ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to use the `--decorate` option. From `man git-log`:

```
       --no-decorate, --decorate[=short|full|auto|no]
           Print out the ref names of any commits that are shown. If short is specified, the ref name prefixes refs/heads/, refs/tags/ and refs/remotes/
           will not be printed. If full is specified, the full ref name (including prefix) will be printed. If auto is specified, then if the output is
           going to a terminal, the ref names are shown as if short were given, otherwise no ref names are shown. The default option is short.
```

I also must mention that on my version of Git (2.20.1), the branches are automatically displayed with `git log`. Which version of Git do you use?

Comment: Yes, most probably a default config issue, with an older version of git. Might be worth checking (or setting) the config entry `log.decorate auto`

Comment: You're right. I found that a git version 2.11 came with my Debian 9.8, and desn't have this configuration set by default.